# Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsById' in IE11

Tags: javascript, excel

I am trying to use java-script to export html data into excel. The funny thing is that it DOES work when I use `getElementsByTagName` instead of `getElementById`. However, I need to pinpoint id elements and thus '`getElementById`' is what I need (I guess). When I debug the below code in IE it gives me:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsById'

Here is what I've got:

HTML (as an idea only):

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>content 1</td>
  <td>content 2</td>
      <td id="R">content I need</td>
      <td>some other content</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

and accompanying JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function write_to_excel() 
{
str="";

var mytable = document.getElementById("R")[0];
var row_Count = mytable.rows.length;
var col_Count = mytable.getElementById("R")[0].getElementById("R").length;    

var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;

for(var i=0; i < row_Count ; i++) 
{   
    for(var j=0; j < col_Count; j++) 
    {           
        str= mytable.getElementById("R")[i].getElementById("R")[j].innerHTML;
        ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1,j+1).Value = str;
    }
}
}
</script>
```

I have the feeling - it's trifle but ... Thanks in advance!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getElementById` method returns a single DOM element (if you have more than one HTML element with the same ID then your page is buggy but browsers won't complain because 10 years ago it was a common bug that lots of people make). As such the statement:

```
document.getElementById("R")[0]
```

Makes no sense whatsoever. Instead, what you want is:

```
var myTD = document.getElementById("R");
```

If you have a page structure like this:

```
<table id='T'>
<tr>
  <td>content 1</td>
  <td>content 2</td>
  <td>content I need</td>
  <td>some other content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And want to iterate each column in each row, you'd do it like this:

```
var mytable = document.getElementById("T");
var table_rows = mytable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var row=0;row<table_rows.length;row++) {
    var row_columns = table_rows[row].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var col=0;col<row_columns.length;col++) {
        var item = row_columns[col];
        // process item here
    }
}
```

See the documentation of HTMLElement for more info on how to navigate the DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element

Full documentation of the DOM API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM

You may also check out the relevant docs on MSDN instead of MDN for IE specific stuff but I prefer MDN because it documents the compatibility level (what other browsers implement a feature) of the API.

Comment: wow, thanks!!! I have just started getting into JS, so sorry if my question looks silly))). Having corrected the file as per above, it now does work, in that it gets the Excel to open sheet and .... nothing jumps in there((((

Comment: Hi, i have similar table, and i get the error :Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName' on line var table_rows = mytable.getElementsByTagName('tr'); first line returns object of type [object DispHTMLElementCollection].. please suggest what can be done..

Answer (score 2):

IDs must be unique.

Therefore, the function you're looking for is called `getElementById` (singular)

Comment: Oh, that's just a typo here, code is right, but thanks anyway!))))

Comment: @Alexander: For the same reason, the function only exists on `document`, not other DOM elements.